# Dual default methods

Tags: haskell

Consider the following classes:

```
class F t where
  f1 :: ...
  f2 :: ...

class F t => G t where
  g1 :: ...
  g2 :: ...
```

Also I can write the following default functions:

1. `f1` in terms of `f2`.
2. `f2` in terms of `f1`.
3. `g1` in terms of `g2`.
4. `g2` in terms of `g1`.
5. `f1` in terms of `g1`, if `G t`.
6. `f2` in terms of `g2`, if `G t`.

Hence, I should be able to do the following:

```
instance F T1 where
  f1 x = (some function of f2)
```

Or:

```
instance F T1
instance G T1 where
  g1 x = (some function of g2)
```

But it seems the only way I can achieve this is to have two default definitions of `f1` and `f2`, but I don't think GHC allows this. Is there anyway I can write this so that for both types that are only of class `F`, and types that are also of class `G`, only have to implement one function?

Comment: Why wouldn't Haskell allow that?

Comment: Why would you write `f1` in terms of either `g` function if having a `G` instances is not a requirement to have an `F` instance? Just define `f1` and `f2` in terms of each other, and ignore the fact that `f` *could* be defined in terms of the `g`s; that's more of a coincidence than a useful fact.

Answer (score 1):

If I get the requirements right, they can be straightforwardly satisfied with a couple of extensions:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances, OverlappingInstances #-}

class F t where
  f1 :: t -> t -> t
  f1 _ = f2
  f2 :: t -> t
  f2 x = f1 x x

class F t => G t where
  g1 :: t -> t -> t
  g1 x _ = g2 x
  g2 :: t -> t
  g2 x = g1 x x

instance G t => F t where
  f1 = flip g1
  f2 = g2

instance F Int where
  f1 = (-)

main = mapM_ print ([f1 4 2, f2 4] :: [Int])

*Main> :main
2
0
```

The `instance` can be changed to `G`:

```
instance G Int where
  g1 = subtract

main = mapM_ print ([f1 4 2, f2 4, g1 4 2, g2 4] :: [Int])

*Main> :main
2
0
-2
0
```

However, I'd consider this solution poor. Could this duality be expressed in some other way? If you provide a concrete example of what `F` and `G` are, a more suitable design may be found.

Comment: OverlappingInstances is deprecated in favor of per-instance OVERLAPPING, OVERLAPPABLE, and OVERLAPS annotations.

Comment: @HTNW Thanks, I have not known about that.

Answer (score 0):

A fairly common idiom for defining subclass methods in terms of the superclass (or is it superclass methods in terms of the subclass? I can never keep it straight) is to expose an explicit `*Default` method, as in

```
class F t where
    {-# MINIMAL f1 | f2 #-}
    f1 = ... f2 ...
    f2 = ... f1 ...

f1Default :: G t => ...
f1Default = ... g1 ...

f2Default :: G t => ...
f2Default = ... g2 ...

class G t where
    {-# MINIMAL g1 | g2 #-}
    g1 = ... g2 ...
    g2 = ... g1 ...
```

This gives the instance-writer control over which default is used.

There are many examples of this pattern in base, including `fmapDefault`, `foldMapDefault`, `bimapDefault`, `bifoldMapDefault`, and [many more](http://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=Default%20&scope=package%3Abase), and I expect there are a fair number of examples of this outside base as well.